# Data recovery for Storage Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Having issue with Google Cloud Platform -> Storage -> Storage
I've heard that google-cloud-storage bucket can recover deleted data for 30days aged. Are there any console solutions or technical support only?

Answer (score 0):

That's not correct - if you want to be able to recover data that you accidentally deleted, you should enable [Object Versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning).

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Cloud Storage documentation for deleting objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes),

> Object deletion cannot be undone. Cloud Storage is designed to give developers a high amount of flexibility and control over their data, and Google maintains strict controls over the processing and purging of deleted data. To protect yourself from mistakes, you can configure [Object versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) on your bucket.

So you will have to enable object versioning to recover deleted objects from bucket. Note that this will incur you additional charges. As per the documentation for [object versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning#details),

> **Caution:** There is no default limit on the number of object versions you can create. Each archived version of an object is charged at the same rate as the live version of the object. If you enable versioning, consider using Object Lifecycle Management, which can remove the oldest versions of an object as newer versions get archived.